# In Scala, is it possible to use implicits to automatically override toString?

Tags: scala

In Java, I would do something like

```
class MyDate extends java.util.Date {
  public String toString() { ... }
}

MyDate date = new MyDate
```

A little bit clunky. In Scala, is it possible to override toString whilst still using regular java.util.Date instead of MyDate.  I have an inkling implicits are involved but would be happy to use any technique

Comment: If you want code that doesn't know about you to use the correct `toString`, you'll have to extend `java.util.Date`; having a different pointer in the method table of that object is the only way it's going to produce a different string!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Implicit conversions can only work if the type being converted does not already have a method with a given signature. As everything has a `toString`, it is not possible to override this by pimping.

What you might do is use a typeclass (akin to `scalaz.Show`) which looks like this:

```
trait Show[-A] {
  def show(a : A): String
}
```

Then you can use `show` everywhere instead of `toString`. Ideally what you want then is to make the `Show[Any]` instance a very low priority implicit.

```
implicit val DateShow = new Show[Date] { def show(d : Date) = "whatever" }

trait LowPriorityShows {
  implicit val AnyShow = new Show[Any] { def show(a : Any) = a.toString }
}
```

*P.S. The reason I would not suggest using `scalaz.Show` is that the return type is `List[Char]`, which is just not practicable for most uses*

Comment: For an explanation about controlling the priority of implicits, see Daniel Sobral's writeup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits